# Is there any way that I can give certain value to google forms inputs

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

Let say I have a question with multiple answers with options like (male, female) and I would like response to be (1,2) in my google apps script result onSubmitForm(). More specifically I am looking something like we do in pure html.

```
<option value="1">Male</option>
<option value="2">Female</option>
```

There is a way that I can add a translator table or ask with if condition for ex:

```
if(response == "female"){ var response = 2;}
```

But this is not what I am looking for, I am looking for some more flexible way as I have more than 100 questions and I don't wanna write code for each question or write a translator table like array or smth.

Comment: There is no way to make a Google Form submit a value that is different than the displayed option/choice.  That would be a nice feature, but that capability does not exist in a Google Form.

Comment: thnx @SandyGood actually that would be so good :)